# Как правильно доступатись к переменной из нескольких потоков?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Учусь работать с потоками, возникла проблема. Как вызывать метод из нескольких потоков понял. А как насчет переменных? Понял что надо использовать модификатор volatile, но надо ли код где используется переменная к которой могут доступиться из разных потоков, обертывать в synchronized()? Не могу найти информацию по этому вопросу.

Пример:

```
public class Main {

public static volatile String var = "1000";

public static class My implements Runnable {
    Thread t;

    My() {
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (var) {
            //Какая то операция над переменной (изменение, чтение)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    My my1 = new My();
    My my2 = new My();
    my1.t.join();
    my2.t.join();
}
}
```

Или можно просто доступиться к переменной без данной обертки?
То есть вот так:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        //Какая то операция над переменной (изменение, чтение)
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Не возникнет ли ошибка когда два потока одновременно доступятся к данной переменной "var", и один попробует ее считать а другой ее изменить?

Буду благодарен за подробное объяснение.

Comment: Смотря что вы собираетесь делать. Если переменная только для чтения и не меняется, то беспокоиться не о чем. Если вы планируете менять переменную, то вам нужно убедиться, что эта операция атомарна (для этого есть [атомарные типы](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html)), если же вы чтото меняете и вам мало атомарной операции (например, если вам нужно выполнить несколько операций синхронно) то тогда вы уже должны использовать синхронизацию. Мало того, `synchronized` это один из самых простых механизмов синхронизации.

Comment: @tym32167 тоесть по сути если надо еще + изменять переменную то synchronized хватит. И можно пренебречь использованием атомарных типов?

Comment: По идее ароматные типы делают операции быстрее, чем если обычный код завернуть в synchronized. Но если скорость работы вам не критична, то вы можете просто использовать synchronized вместо атомарных операций и не париться.

Comment: @tym32167 Большое спасибо за разъяснение!

Comment: Пожалуйста, на здоровье.

Comment: "тоесть по сути если надо еще + изменять переменную то synchronized хватит" - в том виде как написано, нельзя синхронизировать доступ к `var`. `String` в Яве иммутабл, поэтому менять его можно только присвоением нового значения. Как только ты присвоишь новое значение, сразу вся синхронизация слетит, потому что синхронизация в Яве выполняется не на переменной (`var`), а на объекте, на который эта переменная указывает.